# C# Dllimport problems in Visual Studio 2010 .NET framework 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am trying to import a dll written in C++, in my C# application.
The application is supposed to get names of disponible webcams. 
It works well in .NET framework 3.5 (gets all names properly) but I have problems with getting names in framework 4. I get something like "„îş" instead.

Here are fragments of my code :

- c++ dll :

  ```
  TCHAR GetDeviceName(int index)
  {
      char name[255];
      GetDeviceNameAux(index, name);
      TCHAR retVal = (TCHAR)name;
      return retVal;
  }
  ```
- c# application (that works for framework 3.5)

  ```
  [DllImport("FindCaptureDevice.dll")]
  public static extern string GetDeviceName(int index);
  ```

I have tried also :

```
[DllImport("FindCaptureDevice.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern string GetDeviceName(int index);
```

with different parameters for CallingConvention ans CharSet.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: C function does not make sense! Shouldn't it be TCHAR*?

Comment: I have tried TCHAR* with the same effect. And if it does not make any sense why does it work in framework 3.5?

Comment: OK try returning `StringBuilder`

Comment: Do you mind if I post the answer here?

Comment: Assuming you've changed it to return a char*, your C++ code has a big problem.  You're returning an address from the stack.  If this "works", it means you're just getting lucky because the .NET marshaller is copying the contents on the stack before the data is overridden.  Ideally, you would take a char* and a buffer size as input to the C++ function instead of returning a pointer (this also means the caller always owns the memory).  The fact that GetDeviceNameAux doesn't take a size concerns me as well.

Comment: @Peter Huene But one thing that I don't understand is that it works for the earlier versions of framework. I am working on a code written and tested in framework 2, I have run it without any problems in framework 3.5. Only 4 it's not working.

Comment: Returning an address from the stack results in undefined behavior.  It may work, it may cause total protonic reversal (that's bad).  The best way is to have the caller pass in a caller-allocated buffer.  That would mean taking a char* and size.  The C# P/Invoke signature would take a StringBuilder (i.e. StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(255); GetDeviceName(sb, sb.Capacity);) and use CharSet.Ansi.  The calling convention should probably be stdcall (I generally recommend stdcall for exports) by explicitly specifying __stdcall on the C++ exported function.

Comment: +1 for the Ghostbusters reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Thanks to you comments I managed to solve my problem.
I used [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884189/p-invoke-a-function-passed-a-stringbuilder)

and I changed in c# code

```
[DllImport("FindCaptureDevice.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern void GetDeviceName(StringBuilder response, int index);
```

and I call it with

```
StringBuilder tempDevice = new StringBuilder(255);
                GetDeviceName(tempDevice, DevCount);
```

and in c++ code I wrote

```
void GetDeviceName(char * outChr, int index)
{
    GetDeviceNameAux(index, outChr);
}
```

and I copy the data to outChr with strcpy_s method.

Comment: This is still bad C++ code. It assumes that the length of the output buffer (outChr) is "big enough". Don't assume. Change the parameters to include a size. Change the return type to BOOL and if the size passed in is less than 255, return false. And what about the return value of this GetDeviceNameAux?

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I will try to modify it. At least now I know what was wrong. (A GetDeviceNameAux method only gets the name of the device and writes it in outChr.)

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type to `StringBuilder`:

```
[DllImport("FindCaptureDevice.dll")]
public static extern StringBuilder GetDeviceName(int index);
```

Comment: I am afraid it does not work well yet. There is a problem in the end of a device name. Instead of 'Creative WebCam Live! Ultra', I get 'Creative WebCam tË'. And it works only when I run it in Visual Studio, when I try to run it from .exe it does not work.

Comment: As Peter Heune has suggested, I would change the signature to receive a buffer and then fill the buffer. ALthough it would be difficult for me without seeing all the code why it returns wrong character or does not work outside VS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use WIA for capture or scan image